# How to display the multiple error message for a single CustomValidator

Tags: validation, jsf, message

I created the CustomValidator which is called the BoundaryCheckValidator.We need to display the multiple error message for single input component.

```
<h:inputText id="Object__Risk__Group__ContributionAmount"  required="true" requiredMessage="#{validations['Common.ContributionAmountRequiredMessage']}" 
validatorMessage="#{validations['Common.ContributionAmountValidationMessage']}" value="#{automobileRatingManagedBean.attributeValueMap['Object__Risk__Group__ContributionAmount']}" >
 <p:ajax event="blur" listener="#{automobileRatingManagedBean1.save}"  update="UpdatedRiskGroupContributionAmount" />                                                           
 <f:validator validatorId="BoundaryCheckValidator"/>
 <f:attribute name="regexPattern" value="#{dictionary['CommonPattern.USCurrencyWithZero']}"/>
 <f:attribute name="minimumValue" value="#{automobileRatingManagedBean2.saveRequestMap.get('CurrencyMinValue')}"/>
 <f:attribute name="maximumValue" value="#{automobileRatingManagedBean2.saveRequestMap.get('CurrencyMaxValue')}"/>
 <f:attribute name="Type" value="Currency"/></h:inputText>                  
 <h:message for="Object__Risk__Group__ContributionAmount" errorClass="required_error_message" infoClass="validation_error_message" style="color:red" />

        Object maximumVal = component.getAttributes().get("maximumValue");
        if((maximumVal != null) && (!maximumVal.equals("")) && (value != "")){
            maximumValue=component.getAttributes().get("maximumValue").toString();
            maxValue = Double.parseDouble(maximumValue);
            if ( userValue > maxValue) {
                FacesMessage message = new FacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_ERROR,errorMessage,"");   
                throw new ValidatorException(message);  
            }
        }
```

So It possible throw only a single error message. **We won't allowed to use binding attribute, any backing UI components,**.

How do we make it??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since JSF 2.0, the [`ValidatorException`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/faces/validator/ValidatorException.html) class has a [constructor taking `Collection<FacesMessage>`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/faces/validator/ValidatorException.html#ValidatorException(java.util.Collection)).

> #### `ValidatorException`
>
> `public ValidatorException(Collection<FacesMessage> messages)`
>
> Allow this one exception to contain multiple messages.

Just make use of it.

```
List<FacesMessage> messages = new ArrayList<>();
messages.add(new FacesMessage(...));
messages.add(new FacesMessage(...));
...
throw new ValidatorException(messages);
```

Don't forget to replace `<h:message>` in question by `<h:messages>`, otherwise only the first one would be shown:

```
<h:messages for="Object__Risk__Group__ContributionAmount" ... />
```

Note that you can still let it target a specific component via `for`.